# Quantum mechanics and rigorous math

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, probability, quantum-states

I was reviewing a little of quantum mechanics in a rigorous way, so i realized there is a lot of concepts similar in words but different in its meanings, i would appreciate any help to understand it:

Kets -> It is the "physics entity" you are measuring: Momentum, energy, etc...

Operators -> What you actually use to get the results of Momentum, energy, etc...

Eigenkets -> The basis, the possible states the operator can have: exp: Spin up or spin down

Eigenvalues -> The possible values you can get.

Eigenfunctions -> Reserved to wave functions

Eigenvectors -> ?

State vector -> ?

Comment: OBS: i know the math, i want to know the physics meaning

Comment: *OBS: i know the math* With all due respect, if you think that eigenvalues are probabilities you do *not* yet know the math.

Comment: Could you please tell us what textbook you are using to study QM?

Comment: Yeh dont needto appologize, this is the aim of the question, show where i dont understand :)
When i say i know math, i want to say that if you give me a question or ask me the probability of something, i will probably give you an reasonable answer, the problem is exact what you pointed. Thinking a little again, the probability is actually measure using the coefficients, and not the eigenvalues, this was a silly mistake (and show that aim of the question, I mix the concepts), don't worry.
I used Griffiths, he does not talk so much about kets and bra (at leats in the first edition)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Kets**

In quantum mechanics the possible states of the system are elements of a separable, projective Hilbert space (i.e. two states differing by an overall complex constant are equivalent). The kets e.g. $|\psi\rangle$ are elements of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, the bras e.g. $\langle \psi|$ are elements of its dual, $\mathcal H^*$.

---

**Operators**

Each physically measurable quantity is associated with a Hermitian operator, e.g. position $\hat x$, momentum $\hat p$, energy (aka. the Hamiltonian) $\hat H$ etc.

---

**Eigenkets**

These are eigenvectors of the operators that correspond to the observables. Note that since we are dealing with Hermitian operators the eigenkets corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.

*Note, terms often used synonymously with "eigenket" in physics: *Eigenstate, eigenvector, eigenfunction.*

---

**Eigenvalues**

The spectrum of the operators that correspond to observables are the (only) possible values of that quantity that can be obtained upon measurement of the observable in question. Given a system in a state $|\psi\rangle$, the probability of obtaining the value $a$ and (necessarily) finding the system in the associated eigenstate $|a\rangle$ after measuring the observable $\hat A$ is given by: $$\mathrm{Probability}=|\langle a|\psi\rangle|^2 \tag{1}$$

---

**Eigenfunctions**

There is an isomorphism $\mathcal H\cong L^2(\Bbb R)$ that allows us to associate elements of our Hilbert space with elements of the space of square integrable functions, elements of the latter are called wavefunctions.

---

Additional note: You can be more rigorous than this, rigorous quantum mechanics is possible to do but requires a significant amount of heavy lifting and a fair amount of machinery that is not introduced even in fairly advanced courses.

Comment: Hey Charlie. Now that you're getting into high-reputation status, I do want to make sure that you are aware that posts that ask multiple questions go against the site policies. That is why there is a VTC reason of "needs more focus".

Comment: Ok understood, I'll avoid answering questions like this in the future @BioPhysicist

Comment: However, [unit kets are not the most general state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix).

Comment: @J.G. Lots and lots of things that can be said beyond what I've written.

Answer (score 2):

Very short and brief summary of quantum mechanics, please comment if there are mistakes

**Ket vs. State**

Each equivalence class of kets (vectors) which differ from each other by a (multiplicative) complex number is called a ray in Hilbert space (which is a complete inner product space). Each ray represents a state uniquely.

---

The state has many *representations*, the most famous one is the wave function, the so-called position space representation. Another one is the momentum wave function, in momentum space. It is possible to switch between them.

---

**Hermitian operators** (linear maps on the Hilbert space) represent observables, the **eigenvalues** of such an operator are the possible outcomes of a measurement of the corresponding observable, the quantum system takes on a corresponding **eigenstate** (eigenket) immediately after measurement.

---

A **complete set of compatible observables (C.S.C.O)** is a set of observables $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ whose eigekets *can* constitute an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space, such that every eigenket (basis vector) corresponds to a unique tuple $(a_{i_1}^{(1)},a_{i_n}^{(2)},...,a_{i_n}^{(n)})$ of eigenvalues of the C.S.C.O. Each basis vector is denoted $|a_{i_1}^{(1)},a_{i_n}^{(2)},...,a_{i_n}^{(n)}\rangle$. The general state is an "infinite (complex) linear combination" of this basis, The evolution of the state is determined by Schrödinger equation.

---

The **probability** of getting some eigenvalue (as an outcome of a measurement of some observable) is (in case of degeneracy) the (sum of) the squares of the magnitude of the coefficients (of the previous linear combination) that correspond to eigenkets of the considered eigenvalue.

Comment: "the set of all these kets constitutes a Hilbert space" incorrect. Couterexample: a simple Newtonian particle on an infinite 1 dimensional line. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\left| x \right>$ is a ket. There are uncountably many of them and they are all orthogonal to each other, so they don't form a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov please, remove your comment. It is not relevant any more. There is an answer just for your comment on this page now

Comment: I am very confused about what’s happening to my comment. I think it is still relevant — I was trying to highlight that kets are not the same as states, they are more general. Dirac’s ket notation includes distributional objects such as $\left| x \right>$ that are not proper functions and hence don’t belong to the Hilbert space. Kets are a convenient mathematical tool, they are not physical states (or rather, not all of them are). The answer by Ronald that quotes me doesn’t make any sense — I was being completely serious, and I still don’t see how what I said could be seen as a joke.